# Help with <Select Option> Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I am attempting to write several parts of code that work together to show Classic formatted list views (with pages to click through) in Lightning and am barely knowledgable in HTML, CSS and sort of understand Apex. I've been instructed that I need:
1) Apex Class
2) Apex Test Class
3) Apex Controller
4) Apex Test Controller
5) Visualforce Page -and-
6) Component.

I've been able to get basic outlines for all except the Apex Test Class, and no matter what I try, I keep receiving error "Add test methods to your test class."

Can someone please help fix this test class?

Thank you,
Kristen

**Apex Class: NitishContactListViewClass**

```
public class NitishContactListViewClass {
public List<SelectOption> listViewNames{get; set;}
public String conFilterName{get; set;}

public NitishContactListViewClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    String q = 'SELECT Name FROM Contact LIMIT 1'; //Any object whose list view you are trying to retrieve.
    ApexPages.StandardSetController ACC = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(q));
    List<SelectOption> ListViews = ACC.getListViewOptions();
    listViewNames = new List<SelectOption>();
    for(SelectOption w : ListViews ){
        listViewNames.add(new SelectOption(w.getLabel(), w.getLabel()));
    }
}

public PageReference resetFilter() //Dummy function
{
    return null;
}

}
```

**Apex Test Class: NitishContactListViewClass**

```
@isTest
    public class NitishContactListViewClassTest {

@isTest static void NitishContactListViewClass() {
    listViewNames = new List<SelectOption>(00B60000005aJl1EAE)
    System.assertEquals("My Contacts", listViewName );    }

 }
```

Comment: Hi Kristen, welcome to SFSE. We have an extensive collection of resources to help with learning the discipline of Apex unit testing. I've linked this above. Note that at present your test class is not compilable Apex. I would really recommend you sit down with an Apex developer for an hour to get this in shape; your local Salesforce group may be a good resource.

Comment: Hi David, I'd love to sit down with a developer, but as I was just beginning to learn all of this right before covid-19, I have unfortunately not been able to make any connections, hence me coming to the StackExchange. I'll take a look at the link, thank you....I'm at my wits end with this project as I am suppose to be in the Marketing Department and we don't currently have resources for a developer.